# Is it a bad idea to pass a channel contains file handle to goroutine?

Tags: go

ORIGINAL 09/11/2019

```
conn := createConnection() // or a file handle

go getData(conn)
```

Is it possible the thread for `getData`, is in different thread of `conn` handle. Therefore, it can result an connection error.

---- UPDATED 11/11/2019 09am ----

Senario 1

```golang
func createConnection() handler {
  ... create a socket connection (tcp://.....) or file open handler
  return conn
}

func sendData(conn handler, data string) {
  conn.send(data)
}

conn := createConnection() // or a file handle

go sendData(conn, "test data")
```

Senario 2

```golang
func createConnection() handler {
  ... create a socket connection (tcp://.....) or open file handler
  return conn
}

func sendData(ch chan handler, data string) {
  conn := <- ch
  conn.send(data)
}

ch := make(chan conn, 10)

ch <- createConnection() // or a file handle

go sendData(ch, "test data")
```

Story behind:

I was working on a task to proxy data to a socket server. My solution towards the challenge was using the idea of [Senario 2].

Few of my colleagues are C programmer, work with system level programming. They pointed out that golang `channel` better only contains data - put file handler in channel can cause unknow problem, such as: the thread for `channel get` is in different thread of `channel put`, therefore, the file handler can also missing.

To my understanding, golang should solve the problem by itself already. I, then, asked the question above.

By looking into some of the source code of socket related projects, I think [Senario 1] is fine. However, [Senario 2] is still a question to me.

Again, my question is not [can I pass a file handle to a function], everyone knows "It is a yes". The question is in golang CSP, use `go` and `chan` together, with file handler pass through, can it be a problem? Or, more intersetingly: use pointer in golang `channel put` and `channel get` can be a problem or not; it is a big "no no" in C by books. If it is fine in golang, how does golang achive it?

---- UPDATED 11/11/2019 10am ----

The question only apply to golang. Such problem does not happen to node.js, since it is single threaded language. The question focuses on threades and file handler. By the fact, I have limited knowledge around the problem, I apologise to ask bad question or provide miss leading infomation.

---- UPDATED 11/11/2019 10：40am ----

I re-confirmed with my colleague, the concern is "everytime code ask for a file handler, system return a number. Howerver, the number is only unique in one process, which means the same file handler number, in different process, may point to different resource. I am not sure goroutine take care it or not."

Comment: Well it all depends, it doesn't seem wrong to pass the `conn` to a goroutine `getData(conn)`,
As conn is a blocking call. But if the createConnection() just makes conn async and u return before confirming the conn is created it could cause issues.
Similarly u need to make sure that the conn is not closed when being used in the getData

Comment: it is why golang provides numerous mechanisms of synchronization of routines. The language has decided to provide a simpler syntax, but this problem of resources sharing is simply hard, and thus, should be dealt with care with proper apis. Usage of patterns and idioms helps by proving a common ground of understanding to all developers, thus you should use them to solve your issue in a way others can understand rapidly.

Comment: Your title and question seem unrelated. What do you want to know? If something is possible, or if it's a good idea?

Comment: "Is it possible the thread for getData, is in different thread of conn handle. Therefore, it can result an connection error." Non sequitur. The standard HTTP server routinely passes network connections to goroutines.

Comment: @Peter HTTP in most case is not persistent connection, the connection can be created within `getData()`, there is no need to pass the file handler.

Comment: Regarding your update: goroutines are not separate processes, so there's no problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with passing a connection handle to a separate goroutine as long as you are careful about the following:

- Do not close the handle while the goroutine is working, or write the goroutine to deal with it.
- If you are using the handle from multiple goroutines, make sure the connection you're dealing with is thread-safe, or put a lock around it.
- Be clear and explicit about who's going to close it. The goroutine may close it when it is done, or another goroutine closes it when all work using the handle is done.

Comment: My bad, the question is not about connection closed while the goroutine is working, or lock. The connection is a low level persistent connection, such as: socket connection or file open, the used library is only help to constructure the connection and protocol, nothing else. Therefore, the lib does not care about if the thread contains the file handler or not (or at least, it is how C programmer told me).

Comment: What is the "big no no" in C? Sharing handles between threads? It is not a big no no afaik, as long as you serialize the access. I don't understand exactly what scenario in C you're referring to, as there are no channels in C.

Comment: @"Burak Serdar" "everytime code ask for a file handler, system return a number. Howerver, the number is only unique in one process, which means the same file handler number, in different process, may point to different resource." since process contains threades, and goroutine takes care both of them. If process jumps, the file handler can be missing.

Comment: @Zac goroutines and threads belong to one process. They can share handles. A thread or goroutine cannot jump between processes. You cannot pass handles between two processes though there are ways to pass file handles to child processes.

Comment: @"Burak Serdar" thanks, this is the answer I am looking for. Cheers.